# There is similar way code to use this App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION

Tags: ios

My application was rejected on App Store 
Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements

Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality using the "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme.

If there are no alternatives for providing the functionality your app requires, you can file an enhancement request.

apple not allowed using this App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION .
 can any one help me to use  similar way code to use this App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION. that is allowed on App Store.

Comment: The only screen you are allowed to open in the Settings app is the page for your own app. This will include the app's Location privacy setting.

Comment: how to fix this problem to my application to App Store

Comment: @MohamedAliAhmedMohamud use UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString for open setting page  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))